# Cannot set InetMgr.exe as startup program in VS 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-7, iis-7

When I try to set "C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe" as the startup program for a Visual Studio project (to test an IIS 7.5 extension), it is rejected with the message "The external program cannot be found".

If I try to select the EXE manually by clicking the ellipses (...) button, the EXE is not in the folder. But if I access the folder via Windows Explorer, I can see it in the folder. I can also see/execute it from a command line.

I even tried changing the startup program in the project file using notepad and reloading the project, but I just get the same error when I start the project.

How can I debug an IIS 7(.5) extension on Windows 7 if it won't let me start InetMgr.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure *why* it behaves the way it does (it might be Microsoft's response to a "[security flaw](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090130/uac-security-flaw-windows-7-beta-proof/)" found in UAC during the betas), I have found a way around it:

If you check "Use remote machine" and enter "localhost" as the value, it circumvents whatever is blocking access. There might be a performance penalty for using remote debugging, but as it's using the loopback address it shouldn't be significant. The screenshot below shows the settings:

[image: Debug settings for InetMgr.exe]